# Django html forms get value from button

Tags: html, django, forms

Shortly I am busy with the web framework Django, I have already implemented some small projects and wanted to try something bigger, but unfortunately I can not continue at one point and the search has not been promising.
I would like to get displayed on a page single records from my database and by clicking this the server should get a feedback which of the displayed records was clicked.
I currently use some CSS elements from Materialize, but that does not work as well as I would like.

my example.html

```
<head>
</head>

<body>

{% block content %}

<div class="row">
    {% for data in persenal_data %}
        <form action= "{% url 'main:beispiel' %}" method="POST">    {% csrf_token %}
                <button class="col s10 m6 14" type="submit" > # value = data.id 
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card hoverable">
                            <div class="card-content">
                                    <div class="card-title">{{data.id}}
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </button>
            </form>
        {% endfor %}
 </div>
</body>
```

and my views.py

```
def build_reseption_page(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        chusing_data = request.POST.get('value')
        return render(request=request,
                    template_name='main/beispiel.html',
                    context={"personal_data":personal_data})
    else:
        return render(request=request,
                    template_name='main/beispiel.html',
                    context={"personal_data":personal_data})
```

I'd like to assign a variable by clicking the button # value = data.id, that this can be controlled in the views.py.

Comment: <div class="card-title"><input type="hidden" value="{{data.id}}" id="postValue">
                                    </div> try like this and in views.py ===> chusing_data = request.POST.get('postValue')

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the botton both a `name` and a `value`, and then you will be able to obtain the value via `request.POST.get('name', 'default-if-not-present')` in your view. (Often the value is irrelevant, in which case `'name' in request.POST` is all you need).